# Remove "Disconnect" From Server 2012

Tags: group-policy, remote-desktop-services

I have a RDS (Terminal Server) based on Windows Server 2012, and have used the program "Classic Shell" to bring back the Start Menu.

I have setup a test user account (User.1) with the Classic Shell settings I want (with no "Disconnect" option in the Start Menu. I have then put all the registry settings into GPO's (Registry section) and have signed on with a User.2 account onto the RDS server.

My problem is that everything is fine except the "Disconnect" option is still displayed. I can remove it manually from the software option in that user - but would like to set it up for all users that sign on in GPO.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you remove for that user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Classic Shell" and similar programs **do not** "bring back the start menu". The Start Menu has been completely ripped out of Windows 6.2+, there's nothing to bring back. What those programs do is mimic the old Start Menu. It is completely up to the program to implement observance of GPO settings.

Comment: Fair comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Classic Shell is multiuser-friendly. All settings are per user and are stored in the registry. By default, every user can edit all of his settings. An administrator can lock specific settings by copying the same setting which exists in the HKCU\Software\IvoSoft registry branch to the HKLM\Software\IvoSoft branch, so that no other user can edit them and the setting becomes enforced for all users. HKLM means the setting becomes enforced for all users.